# How Can I disable the virtual keyboard?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-ce, smart-device

I'm developping an application for Honeywell Dolphin 6100, a mobile computer with a barcode scanner that uses Windows CE 5.0 like OS.

I employed in my app. an "openFileDialog" compenent, but the the problem is that a virtual keyboard is showing when the field of the file name is focused, how should disable it or make it invisible ?

Any help on this ?

**Note**: I'm using VS2008 (C#) and I'm working on Windows 7.

I tried to modify the registery by using the code below but with no success :

```
        RegistryKey rkey = Registry.CurrentUser;
        RegistryKey wtaKey = rkey.OpenSubKey(@"ControlPanel\Sip", true);
        try
        {
            wtaKey.SetValue("AllowChange", "dword:0");
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`InputPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.inputpanel%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class and set it's `Enabled` property to `false`;

**EDIT 1**

To disable it system-wide, set the following registry key (requires a soft reset afterward):

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\Sip]
    AllowChange=dword:0
```

**EDIT 2**

The value is a DWORD (integer in C#) and the value is zero, so something like this:

```
using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("ControlPanel\\Sip"))
{
    key.SetValue("AllowChange", 0);
}
```

Comment: it's not working, when the file open dialog is open, the input panel still active  !!!

Comment: it's possible to do it with code (i will install my app. into many honeywell devices, so I will not edit the registry for each machine)

Comment: Yes, your code can write registry keys.  See the `RegistryKey` class.

Comment: Yes I know but I don't know how to do that, I mention that I working with WinCE !! I used the code like above but with no result !!

Comment: :( It's still not working; when I try to open the "openFileDialog" the virtual keyboard still existing . **PS**: the registery class is existing on Microsoft.Win32 instead of Microsoft.WindowsCE. Is that correct to use it on a WinCE device ?

Comment: Did you reset the device after making the change?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
        try
        {
            RegistryKey myKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("ControlPanel\\SIP", true);
            if (myKey != null)
            {
                myKey.SetValue("TurnOffAutoDeploy", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                myKey.Close();
            }
        }
        catch { }
```

Comment: Adding some explanation as to what the code does differently and why that resolves the issue would make your answer much better. Generally answers that explain the solutions rather than just copy and paste answers are preferred here at StackOverflow.